# Spark K-Means get original Cluster Center / Centroids with Normalization

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cluster-analysis, normalization, k-means

I ran a k-means model

```
val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(k).setSeed(1L)
val model = kmeans.fit(train_dataset)
```

and then extract the cluster centers (centroids)

```
 var clusterCenters:Seq[(Double,Double,Double,Double,Double,Double,Double,Double,Double)] = Seq()
for(e <- model.clusterCenters){
  clusterCenters = clusterCenters :+ ((e(0)),e(1),e(2),e(3),e(4),e(5),e(6),e(7),e(8))
}

import sc.implicits._
var centroidsDF = clusterCenters.toDF()
```

to write the results back I create a DataFrame of the resulting cluster centers.

Now I have the problem that I have normalized the data beforehand to improve the clustering results.

```
 val scaler = new StandardScaler()
      .setInputCol("features")
      .setOutputCol("scaledFeatures")
      .setWithStd(true)
      .setWithMean(false)
    scalerModel = scaler.fit(train_dataset)
    scaledData = scalerModel.transform(train_dataset)
```

How can I get the centroids in its original form de-normalized?

Comment: How do you know this improved the results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if it makes any sense to do it, but since don't center, you can just multiply by `std` vector:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.ElementwiseProduct

val kmeans: KMeansModel = ???
val scaler: StandardScalerModel = ???

new ElementwiseProduct()
  .setScalingVec(scaler.std)  // Standard deviation used by scaler
  .setOutputCol("rescaled")
  .setInputCol("cluster")
  .transform(sc.parallelize(
    // Get centers and convert to `DataFrame`
    kmeans.clusterCenters.zipWithIndex).toDF("cluster", "id"))
```